# Apply multiple functions to each row of a numpy array

Tags: python, function, numpy, vectorization

Let's say we have a matrix of 3 rows and 2 columns as `mat`, and I want to apply on each 3 row one of the functions of list `what_functions_to_apply_list` for which I have their definition. So the output of  `np.apply_along_axis` should be 3 rows times the output dimension of the functions.

How can I do this without for looping in a vectorized way?

e.g.

```
def f1(inp1,inp2):
     return out1, out2
```

where

```
 functions_dic = {'f1': func1, 'f2':func2, 'f3':func3}
 what_functions_to_apply_list = ['f1','f1','f2']
 funcs_inputs = [[inp11,inp12], [inp21,inp32], [inp31,inp32]]
 mat = np.ones((3, 2))
 np.apply_along_axis(what_functions_to_apply_list , 1, mat)
```

Comment: You can't. Applying a custom function like this will necessarily require a call to Python and it will run in `for`-loop speed

Comment: `apply_along_axis` isn't meant for that kind of use.  For a start, the first argument is a function, not a list of functions.  Even with a correct function it isn't faster alternative to explicit iteration.  It is not a 'no-loop vectorized' tool.

Comment: Please add sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight forward application of a list of functions to the rows of an array:

```
In [418]: alist = [np.add, np.subtract, np.multiply]                            
In [419]: data = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)                                      
In [420]: [foo(*ab) for foo, ab in zip(alist, data)]                            
Out[420]: [1, -1, 20]
```

Comment: how about providing inputs to each function as well

Comment: This is providing inputs, the rows of `data`.  If you mean other parameters (e.g. axis), you'll have to create functions (or lambdas) that set those first.